# A datatable that references a union of another datatable C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I require 2 `Datatables` for my C# application. First table is populated from database. Second table needs to be built dynamically so it duplicates each row in the first table 3 times, and presents a subset of the columns with different column names.

So far I have achieved this by building 3 `linq` queries and then concatenating the result. E.g.

```
var query1 = from result in MainDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             MyRowID = result.Field<string>("MyRowID"),
                             Type = "ABC",
                             ScheduleDate = result.Field<DateTime>("Date1")
                         };

var query2 = from result in MainDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             MyRowID = result.Field<string>("MyRowID"),
                             Type = "DEF",
                             ScheduleDate = result.Field<DateTime>("Date2")
                         };

var query3 = from result in MainDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         select new
                         {
                             MyRowID = result.Field<string>("MyRowID"),
                             Type = "GHI",
                             ScheduleDate = result.Field<DateTime>("Date3")
                         };

var queryFinal = query1.Concat(query2).Concat(query3);
```

I then set queryFinal as the datasource for my calendar component.

But any changes to the contents of `MainDataTable` are not present in the `datasource` for the calendar component until I run the above code again. Is it possible to build an object or query that instead of copying, is referencing `MainDataTable` data and therefore refreshes automatically?

Comment: The queries are referencing the datatables, so if you really modify that table on changes you should see them in the result of the queries. Maybe you have to reassign the datasource to your component.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, but the `queryFinal`, that's being used to data bind, is filled with anonymous types right? So if the row changes for whatever reason, the binding needs to occur again (not surprising). I think the OP is looking for a mechanism where the `queryFinal` is more attached to the reference of the `DataRow`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: The query is not "filled" since `Concat` does not execute the query, it is deferred executed. So unless you don't call `ToList`, `foreach` or other executing methods this will not evaluate and it will be evaluated once more when the query will be executed next time.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, that is correct - I do not wish to have to reassign the datasource or refresh etc. the datasource at any time - this should simply present the current data within `MainDataTable`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I was hoping that was the case but in my application the data in the calendar component is not representing any changes made to the `MainDataTable` - I have to call the above code again. Granted, it is assigning `queryFinal` as the datasource in the same function as I've included above - so it is possible that initialising the datasource just once, and then reassigning each time a change occurs, might do the job. But still means I need a function called from each of the several other areas of the application  that can modify `MainDataTable`. Hence looking for an cleaner way

Comment: @JGreasley: Have you tried to use a `BindingSource` on the query(my winforms skills are a bit rusty)? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Not yet, I'll check your article and let you know if it helps. Thanks

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Having read the above I agree that the use of `BindingSource` is probably the right way to go to solve the problem. But my attempts to link `MainDataTable` to the LINQ query via `BindingSource` are not working. I don't have enough time right now to pursue this idea any further so for now I am calling a method to rebind the datasource manually after updates to `MainDataTable`. Hopefully I'll get a chance to revisit it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

So the only solution I can think of at the moment would be to wrap the `DataRow` in an object. Consider this class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private DataRow _model;
    private string _dateField;

    public ViewModel(DataRow row, string dateField)
    {
        _model = row;
        _dateField = dateField;
    }

    public string MyRowID
    {
        get { return _model.Field<string>("MyRowID"); }
        set { _model["MyRowID"] = value; }
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public DateTime ScheduleDate
    {
        get { return _model.Field<DateTime>(_dateField); }
        set { _model[_dateField] = value; }
    }
}
```

and now in your LINQ statement, build a `ViewModel` instead of the anonymous type you are now:

```
var query1 = from result in MainDataTable.AsEnumerable()
             select new ViewModel (result, "Date1");
```

and now the model in the final query will be leveraging the instance of the row. If it changes, you'll get new values, but if you change it, it will also update the row.

Comment: Was hoping that the solution works both ways, so any update to the calendar component is also made to the `MainDataTable`. So if this works, great! I'll let you know how I get on with the above

Comment: This approach does improve my solution as any updates to the bound calendar component are now made directly to the `DataRow`. But updates to the `MainDataTable` are not automatically present in the calendar component - I have to rebind the datasource to see these changes. Using `BindingSource` as suggested by TimSchmelter does appear to be on the right track but I can't get it to work with the complexity of my _union_ style problem. Any further ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kinds of **changes** are you making to the `MainDataTable`?

Comment: The user can update date fields in >1 location. If they select one (or more) rows in the `DataGridView` and choose to _Update Date1_ they can amend the date. Alternatively they can view the calendar component, drag & drop an entry and this will also update Date1. Regardless of how they update Date1 I want the `MainDataTable` to reflect the change, and for both the `DataGridView` and the calendar control to show the current Date1 value without having to call methods to rebind DataSources in all locations that reference `MainDataTable`

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just duplicate the rows, remove unwanted columns, and rename existing columns?

```
        DataTable tbl2 = MainDataTable.Clone();

        tbl2.Merge(MainDataTable.Copy());
        tbl2.Merge(MainDataTable.Copy());
        tbl2.Merge(MainDataTable.Copy());

        tbl2.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
        tbl2.Columns.RemoveAt(1);

        tbl2.Columns[0].ColumnName = "SomeName";
        tbl2.Columns[1].ColumnName = "SomeName";
```

Comment: This does not achieve the required "reference" to the original `MainDataTable`. This creates a new `datatable`, populates with the required data, and yes it works as a datasource. But as soon as a change is made to data within `MainDataTable`, `tbl2` is redundant and needs to be rebuilt again